# What is this error: NameError: name 'mouseX' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import pygame
dx = 3
dy = 4
x = 100
y = 100
radius = 20
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseX = event.pos(0)
            mouseY = event.pos(1)
        if distance((mouseX, mouseY), (x,y)) <= radius:
            dx = dx+sign(dx)
            dy = dy+sign(dy)
            score = score + 1
        else:
            exit()
    t = font.render ("Score: "+str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
    display.blit (t, (20,20))

    display.fill((100, 100, 100))
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
    pygame.draw.circle (display, (200,200,200), (x,y), radius)
    if (x< radius or x>500- radius):
        dx = -dx
    if (y< radius) or (y>300- radius):
        dy = -dy


    pygame.display.update()
```

Why is this error showing up?
I have defined my `mouseX` as `mouseX = event.pos(0)`. Does this mean that I am supposed to use another variable  or use global variable? If so then how do I add global variable?

Comment: Please share the entire Traceback error

Comment: if this line is false -->`if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`   then mouseX is never defined so when you move on to this line  `if distance((mouseX, mouseY), (x,y))...`   mouseX doesn't exist and it throws error

Comment: @ Eshaan Gupta, answering:Please share the entire Traceback error
this is the error: ''' pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code\Jet Boat.py", line 19, in <module>
    if distance((mouseX, mouseY), (x,y)) <= radius:
NameError: name 'mouseX' is not defined'''

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario, where the first if statement's condition is false, that is, mouse button is not pressed, the variables mouseX and mouseY are never defined. Hence when you try to access them in the subsequent lines, the error.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #if this is false
            mouseX = event.pos(0)  #this statement is not executed
            mouseY = event.pos(1)  #this statement is not executed
        if distance((mouseX, mouseY), (x,y)) <= radius: #hence accessing the mouseX variable here throws the error
            dx = dx+sign(dx)
            dy = dy+sign(dy)
            score = score + 1
        else:
            exit()
```

You should probably try initialising the variables mouseX and mouseY to something first.

Comment: um how do i do that?
im new to python programming and this code was actually done by someone else(james r parker, authour of game programming in python)
and when i got this error i went to his website and used the original code files and it still shows the error

Comment: Please share the code for the distance() function

Comment: The distance function is actually a global variable.